# Strange permission behavior into nested folders

Tags: security, plone

Plone 4.3.1 + Dexterity (p.a.dexterity 2.0.8, p.dexterity 2.1.3)

Folder structure: /Plone/A/B

I want `A` to be visible to loggedin users, and `B` to be manageable by `userx` (meaning he/she can modify/add/etc).

Usual approach:

A -> sharing tab -> logged in -> can view
B -> sharing tab -> userx -> can add

Then you go to B and you can do everything BUT add content.

But, if you give userx 'Contributor' role on the portal, it works. So, the role that he/she needs on the context is 'Contributor'. Ok, let's check it!

Go to debug shell, traverse to folder, check local roles: everything's ok! The user has the local role.

After a lot of attempts and combinations of settings I found that this works:

A -> add new menu -> restrictions -> change "use parent settings" to "use site default"
B -> add new menu -> restrictions -> "use parent settings"
Aaaaand... it works!

If I remember well, it never worked like that? Is this a regression that has been fixed later?

Comment: I tried your steps on a stock Plone 4.3.3, and the "Add new" menu is populating with all the content items.

Comment: yep, it works on 4.3.4 too, but not 4.3.1 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the bug we fixed on plone.app.dexterity 2.1.2.
https://github.com/plone/plone.app.dexterity/pull/127

You can upgrade to this version also on Plone 4.3.